# Removing spaces before ```center```

Tags: verbatim, center, fontfamily

```
\documentclass[12pt] {article}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\def\baselinestretch{2.0}
\titleformat{\paragraph}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\setlength{\textwidth}{18cm} 
\setlength{\textheight}{21cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.15cm}
\newcommand{\toright}[1]{%
    \leavevmode\unskip\nobreak\hfill\penalty13 
    \null\nobreak\hskip1em plus1fill\hbox{#1}%
}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.15cm}
\title{\textbf{XXXXXX}}
\author{XXXXXXX}
\affil{\textbf{XXX}\;XXXX}
\affil{\textbf{XXX}\;XXXX}
\date{}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle\vspace{-1cm}
    \newpage
    \tableofcontents
    \pagestyle{fancy} \fancyhf{} 
    \fancyhead[LO]{XXXX}
    \fancyhead[RE]{XXXX}
    \fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage} 
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
    
    \newpage
    \begin{enumerate}
        \section{ABC}
    \item value to the \verb|main| function. Instead it displays the result on the console. So we write {\fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont void sum (int a, int b)}. \\
    The \verb|main| function accepts the inputs and find \verb|sum| function in it. Suddenly it calls the \verb|sum| function and sends the inputs to \verb|sum| function. The \verb|sum| function takes the inputs and calculates the result and displays it on the console. Then the function control automatically returns to the \verb|main| function and finds the closing brace "$\}$" and terminates the program.
    \item \textbf{function with no argument and return type:}\\
    Here the \verb|sum| function has no argument and therefore we write \verb|sum()| (or we can write {\fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont sum (void)}). Since the function has return type (suppose \verb|int|), so we write \verb|int sum()| or {\fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont int sum(void)}.\\
    Here the \verb|main| function at first finds the \verb|sum| function and calls it. The \verb|sum| function then accepts the inputs and calculates. Since the \verb|sum| function has return type, so it returns the result to the \verb|main| function. \verb|main| function then receives the results and prints it on the console.
    \begin{center}
        \begin{BVerbatim}
    /* Adding two numbers using function*/
#include<stdio.h>
int sum ();                
            
void main ()
{
   int c;                 
   c= sum();   
   printf("\n The sum is = %d",c);
}
            
int sum ()     
{
   int x,y,z;
   printf("Enter the two numbers: ");
   scanf("%d, %d", &x, &y);
   z= x+y;
   return z;
}
        \end{BVerbatim}
    \end{center}
    \item \textbf{function with no argument and no return type:}\\
    Here the \verb|sum| function has no argument and therefore we write \verb|sum()| (or we can write {\fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont sum (void)}). Since the function has no return type, so we write \verb|void sum()| or {\fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont void sum(void)}.\\
    Here the \verb|main| function at first finds the \verb|sum| function and calls it. The \verb|sum| function then accepts the inputs and calculates. Since the \verb|sum| function has no return type, so it cannot return the result to the \verb|main| function. So the \verb|sum| function itself prints the result on the console. Then the function control automatically returns to the \verb|main| function and finds the closing brace "$\}$" and terminates the program.
    \begin{center}
        \begin{BVerbatim}
    /* Adding two numbers using function*/
#include<stdio.h>
void sum ();                
            
void main ()
{
   sum();                
}
            
void sum ()     
{
   int x,y,z;
   printf("Enter the two numbers: ");
   scanf("%d, %d", &x, &y);
   z= x+y;
   printf("\n The sum is = %d",z);
}
        \end{BVerbatim}
    \end{center}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

As far as I know, I cannot break `center` into multiple pages. But I need these coding in the middle (center alignment) of the page. So if I remove `center` and use `verbatim`, then the blank spaces are removed but the coding become left aligned to the page.
So what do I require to have

1. coding center aligned
2. fonts are `qcr`
3. breaks pages
   all together.

I can use `{\fontfamily \selectfont {text}}` but I think this process is quite laborious for large coding.

**EDIT: I don't want to decrease `\def\baselinestretch{2.0}` to 1 or something less than 2.**

Comment: "As far as I know, I cannot break center into multiple pages."  `center` doesn't have any effect on page breaking. but you are using a boxed verbatim and boxes do not split over pages.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle without boxed verbatim, how do I center the coding (with that font style)? Does ```center``` work on ```verbatim```?  I used it but didn't work.

Comment: no verbatim can't be centered as it allows page breaking so each line is a normal full width paragraph,  tcolorbox and other packages provide breakable boxes

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but ```tcolorbox[breakable]``` won't middle it, right? I needed that too

Comment: even a standard verbatim will "center" if you set the left margin appropriately, the trick is to know the length of the largest line to know how much to indent. One long line can move it visually off center so to be honest I wouldn't center I'd just indent by something that looks centered fro a typical line length.